# How to check if a letter is in a string

Tags: python

I am making hang man.

I am letting the user enter one letter at a time and I have two different lists holding the right and wrong letters. The issue is for some reason no matter if the letter is in the word it goes to the wrong list no matter what I do. For example for the world "hello"

if the user enters an "h"

the right box should look like this "h"
and the wrong box should be empty
if the user the enters an f the right box should look like this "h"
the wrong box should look like this "f" and so on.

I thought I made the perfect logic for it but it seems to be not working wright because everything the user types seems to be going to the wrong box. My code is attached in the image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vxivt.png)

Comment: `'h' in 'hello'` is True and `'f' in 'hello'` is False

Comment: You forgot your code

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the shortest complete program that demonstrates the problem you are having. See [mcve] for more info.

Comment: Did you do any research before asking this? Try googling "python check if letter is in string"

Comment: Please do not link screenshots of your code. Use the provided code tags to paste it, so people can easily copy, modify and re-paste your code in their solution, if necessary.

Comment: I believe your problem is that you're checking the user's input character against the `hold_random_word` **list**, so when you enter a letter, you're basically saying:  Is `h` in `['hello']`, which it is not.  `hello` is the only thing in `['hello']`.

Answer (score 1):

```
word = 'hello'
right_letters = []
wrong_letters = []

def guess(letter):
    if letter in word:
        right_letters.append(letter)
    else:
        wrong_letters.append(letter)
```

Answer (score 0):

**A Quick fix !!!**

replace the following two lines:

```
hold_random_word = []
hold_random_word.append(random_word)
```

with:

```
hold_random_word = [i for i in random_word]
```

And your code will work !!!

---

**Problem in your code:**

Because `hold_random_word` is a list of strings. So when you write:

```
if i in hold_random_word:
```

it compares every string present in the `hold_random_word` list with `i`.

for example if  `hold_random_word = ["str","str1","str2"]` and character `ch = 's'`, The expression `if ch in hold_random_word:` will compare `ch`(which is 's') with `"str"` (`if 's' == "str" ?` No) and then `"str1"` (`if 's' == "str1" ?` No) and then `"str2"` (`if 's' == "str2" ?` No). No match found, so it will return `False`.